# Java - Cut a string programmatically

Tags: java, string

I have a string (URL) like this:

```
"https://www9.online-convert.com/dl/web2/download-file/248f2225-7ed3-48dd-a586-ac1390bbeaab/02_Cuppy_lol.webp"
```

I need to extract the last part only i.e. `02_Cuppy_lol.webp`.

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Split on `/` and retrieve the last element.

Comment: You should first try to do it by yourself and post your progress here, this way you encourage people to help you too.

Comment: I see that you're a new contributor, welcome to the site. 

Please read the help docs. Start here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 

You should always do some research before you ask and you should also post the things you tried

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `substring()` and `lastIndexOf()` here:

```
String value = completeString.substring(completeString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: why i use "+ 1" at last?

Comment: @FauzeeOfficial Because `lastIndexOf()` returns the index of last `/` but we don't want it to be included in our substring. That's why we skipped that index. I hope you got it?

Answer (score 1):

You can split this text/url and get last part, for example:

```
String url = "https://www9.online-convert.com/dl/web2/download-file/248f2225-7ed3-48dd-a586-ac1390bbeaab/02_Cuppy_lol.webp";
String[] splittedUrl = url.split("/");
String lastPart = splittedUrl[splittedUrl.length()-1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the method split().follow this example

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str ="https://www9.online-convert.com/dl/web2/download-file/248f2225-7ed3-48dd-a586-ac1390bbeaab/02_Cuppy_lol.webp";
        String[] temp=str.split("/");
        int lastIndex =temp.length-1;
        String lastPart = temp[lastIndex];
        System.out.println(lastPart);
    }
}
```

Output-:

```
02_Cuppy_lol.webp
```